# Meaning of "I" in the R Language

Tags: r

Naturally, I had little success searching Google for "R I", "I in R", and "R language I".

- The [R help](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/AsIs.html) says "Change the class of an object to indicate that it should be treated ‘as is’.".
- My O'Reilly R book doesn't have an entry for it in its index.
- My Cambridge book essentially says, about "I(logdist^2)": "ensures that is taken as the square, rather than as an interaction of logdist".

Can someone explain the "interaction" comment? Can someone explain why "logdist^2" wouldn't be interpreted in the traditional way?

Comment: The phrase you're quoting about being or not being interpreted "in a traditional way" is easy to understand, when you consider the context of use of `I()` in linear models _formula_, where elements are considered part of formula syntax (as _terms_) by default. So, `I()` reverses the default meaning.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I think it starts to make more sense as an "identity" function, but the discussion (thanks for sharing) seems to imply that R miscasts things or processing complex expressions. Is I() a sort of hack to get past that? To your second comment, that's helpful. I'm only just learning R, but I could understand it implying a mode change, of sorts.

Comment: No worries. I've removed my comment. You may want to read up on R formula notation; that's the main context where you'll use `I()` (i.e., to override the formula rules); e.g., see http://science.nature.nps.gov/im/datamgmt/statistics/r/formulas/

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Thanks, Jeromy. That's helpful. I'm sure the formula notation is a stumbling block for new programmers unless they're properly prepped for it.

Answer (score 10):

From p89 of R in a Nutshell

Caret(`^`) [is] Used to indicate crossing to a specific degree. For example:

```
y~(u+w)^2
```

is equivalent to

```
y~(u+w)*(u+w)
```

Identity function (`I()`) Used to indicate that the enclosed expression should be interpreted by it's arithmetic meaning. For example

```
a+b
```

means that both a and b should be included in the formula. The formula:

```
I(a+b)
```

means that "*a* plus *b*" should be included in the formula. See also `?AsIs()`

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is that `I` is very rarely used as a standalone operator.  As the help page states, it's most often used to stop operator characters (^,+,*, etc) from being interpreted as they are in a  `formula` .  As user2633645 's answer says, these characters have specific meanings in a `formula` .  Quoting from the help page for `stats::formula` ,

> The ~ operator is basic in the formation of such models. An expression of the form y ~ model is interpreted as a specification that the response y is modelled by a linear predictor specified symbolically by model. Such a model consists of a series of terms separated by + operators. The terms themselves consist of variable and factor names separated by : operators. Such a term is interpreted as the interaction of all the variables and factors appearing in the term.
>   In addition to + and :, a number of other operators are useful in model formulae. The * operator denotes factor crossing: a*b interpreted as a+b+a:b. The ^ operator indicates crossing to the specified degree. For example (a+b+c)^2 is identical to (a+b+c)*(a+b+c) which in turn expands to a formula containing the main effects for a, b and c together with their second-order interactions. The %in% operator indicates that the terms on its left are nested within those on the right. For example a + b %in% a expands to the formula a + a:b. The - operator removes the specified terms, so that (a+b+c)^2 - a:b is identical to a + b + c + b:c + a:c. It can also used to remove the intercept term: when fitting a linear model y ~ x - 1 specifies a line through the origin. A model with no intercept can be also specified as y ~ x + 0 or y ~ 0 + x.
>   While formulae usually involve just variable and factor names, they can also involve arithmetic expressions. The formula log(y) ~ a + log(x) is quite legal. When such arithmetic expressions involve operators which are also used symbolically in model formulae, there can be confusion between arithmetic and symbolic operator use.
>   To avoid this confusion, the function I() can be used to bracket those portions of a model formula where the operators are used in their arithmetic sense. For example, in the formula y ~ a + I(b+c), the term b+c is to be interpreted as the sum of b and c.